# Kobuki base - Jerky move with Nav goal (move_base)

Tags: navigation, move-base, kobuki

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello experts,

I had set up a Turtlebot 2 Kobuki base with ROS indigo Hokuyo lidar, Navigation stack and Gmapping n produce a map from the small area that im working in... all works perfectly and the map is totally consistent, when i move the robot around the room with the Keyop (teleop) but when it comes to publishing a navigation goal or Twist command i have a problem;

1. i wrote a simple node to publish Twist messages to my Kobuki base with no reaction from the robot until i found out that for the Twist cmds to work with my kobuki I have to send them to `/mobile_base/commands/velocity` instead of `/cmd_vel` or do a little remapping for these topics in Kobuki base lauchfiles. long story short, if i dont remap; standard Twist msg dont work, e.g: setting a nav_goal in Rviz for move_base gets no reaction from the robot, etc. but when i remap /cmd_vel to the other topic and then send a goal, my robot acts weird and jumps n snaps (jerky moves) and doesnt seem to stop until i force "ctrl-c" or turn it off.
   i have no idea what might be problem and found no useful resource on this matter... has anyone faced a similar problem with Kobuki mobile base or have any ideas?

- ps: tried mapping `/mobile_base/commands/velocity` to both `cmd_vel` and `cmd_vel_mux` and outcome is the same jumpy and sudden moves.

please do ask if u need me to elaborate or send config files.

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205064/kobuki-base---jerky-move-with-nav-goal-(move_base)/) by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 116 on 2015-03-16

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Actually in the Kobuki base model they included a multiplexer to receive & prioritise inputs from different sources, so this is not (wasn't) the problem. problem was that `controller_frequency:` parameter wasn't right and also a very big X,Y size (meters) for Costmap Local and Global maps in the move_base setting could cause this jerky behaviour. just lower the size to a reasonable amount and it works smooth. (100 x 100; lowered to 40x40 and its all good).

---

Originally posted by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) with karma: 116 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jseal](https://answers.ros.org/users/20018/jseal/) on 2015-04-29**:
Just curious what value did you use for the controller_frequency?

**Comment by [sobot](https://answers.ros.org/users/21730/sobot/) on 2015-05-02**:
@jseal it was set to 4 or 5 if i remember correctly, i raised it to 20 and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should not run key teleop and sending navigation goal together. Kill the key teleop shell and then try sending navigation goal. This will not give jerky motion.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2015-03-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4